# I do not understand this Django error

Tags: python, django

Error during template rendering

> In template
>   C:\Users\Paddy\Desktop\Django-tut\mysite\blog\templates\blog\post_list.html,
>   error at line 10 Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '()' and
>   keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['blog/post/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="post">
        {% if post.published_date %}
            <div class="date">
                {{ post.published_date }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>

        <!--<h1><a href="">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>-->

        <p>{{ post.text|linebreaks }}</p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

My **post_detail.html** file looks like this

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="post">
        {% if post.published_date %}
            <div class="date">
                {{ post.published_date }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ post.text|linebreaks }}</p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

My **urls.py** is

```
    from django.conf.urls import include, url
    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
        url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    ]
```

and **views.py** is

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post
def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
    #Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
# Create your views here.

def post_list(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {})
```

Thanks.

Comment: replace `pk=post.pk` with `post.pk`

Comment: Thanks but no change.

Comment: That should do make it work, are you sure you replaced it in the url tag in the first template?

Comment: Id did but I still receive the same error.

Comment: You are not passing any QuerySet list in the `post_list` view, that is causing the error, first add it to the context and then loop through the list in the template and it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the first template you've posted is `post_list.html` you don't send any context variables to it.

In `post_list` view - if you want to list all posts - you have to add:

```
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Then in your **post_list.html** template you have to loop over `posts`:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %} # iterate over posts
    <div class="post">
        {% if post.published_date %}
            <div class="date">
                 {{ post.published_date }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>

        <p>{{ post.text|linebreaks }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

There error message complains that it can't find a reverse URL when pk is `''`, the empty string.

Indeed there is no URL that matches that, as the regular expression required `[0-9]+`, and the empty string doesn't match that. So a reverse match can't be found.

The reason why pk was empty is explained in the other answer.